# back button for form preview in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, back-button

I have a problem while making a back button for form in rails.
I have a dynamic form that looks like this:
[dynamic form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftkg8.png)

However, when I press 'preview' button, the page will redirect to another page. In this page, I have created button:

```
<%= button_to 'Back to edit', 'javascript:history.go(-1);', {class:'btn btn-primary'} %>
```

It really back to previous form, but only 1 single form displayed
[returned form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZFzb.png)

Can anyone can help me???

Answer (score 2):

You can do this follow as:

```
<%= link_to 'Back to edit', :back %>
```

Comment: `link_to :back` is just a helper method that generates javascript to navigate back. I'm pretty sure this does the exact same thing as `button_to 'Back to edit', 'javascript:history.go(-1);'`

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will cache the back action and therefore won't issue an HTTP request to  your server. If you need to display fresh data, then use a redirect via javascript's `window.location` rather than relying on the history state.